# Here maps change language for map controls dynamically

Tags: javascript, web, translation, here-api, heremaps

With here maps there is possibility to change language for both layers and controls. Here is example from here maps. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.1.0/heremaps/jsfiddle-github/tree/master/map-multi-language-support . The problem I'm having with this example is that it changes control translation with this line of code:

`var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers, 'zh-CN');`.

It's good for initial language, but what if I have a button that would change language, would I need to recreate this ui variable every time I would want to change control language? Is there no method like H.ui.UI.setLocale or something(I tried to search but couldn't find).

Answer (score 0):

We suggest removing the old instance of the UI element and then creating the new one with the desired language.

H.ui.UI class offers the dispose() method to remove the object.  To learn more, please refer to the following online doc.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.26.0/api_reference/H.ui.UI.html#dispose

Here are the sample codes, and hopefully, it helps.

```
var ui,defaultLayers,platform,map;
 
function switchMapLanguageToCN(){

  switchLanguage("zh-CN")
}


function switchMapLanguageToEN(){
  
  switchLanguage("en-US")
}


function switchLanguage(language){


  if(typeof(ui) == "object"){
    ui.dispose();
  }
  ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers, language);
}
```